# Regarding embeddings and homological/cohomological injectivity

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, homology-cohomology, symplectic-geometry, symplectic-linear-algebra

Possibly low-level question here: if one has an embedding $M\hookrightarrow X$, call it $\iota$, then this is of course an immersion, so the differential maps $\iota_{\ast}:T_{p}M\rightarrow T_{\iota(p)}X$ are injective for every $p\in M$.  Does this imply that $\iota$ induces an injective map on homology, or cohomology?  If not, what are the known conditions on $\iota$ that would guarantee these types of injectivity?  I am seeking to select a class of symplectic embeddings $(M,\sigma)\hookrightarrow (X,\omega)$ that are cohomologically injective.

My question is initially rather low, I recognize, but it blooms into something that requires more investigation.  In lieu of an answer, I would appreciate some nice sources for more directed investigation.  I am seeking topological enlightenment, but 'homologically injective' as search terms returns mostly algebraic research, much to my chagrin.

Comment: The inclusion $S^1 \hookrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is not injective on homology or cohomology.

Comment: What coefficients are you interested in? With field coefficients you can look at Qiaochu's answer and pretty much just dualize to get rather nice conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. For example, $S^2$ embeds into $\mathbb{R}^3$, and this doesn't induce an injection on homology. Similarly, $\mathbb{R}^2$ embeds into $S^2$, and this doesn't induce an injection on cohomology.

In general it's tricky to guarantee injections or surjections on homology or cohomology. For an embedding $i : A \to X$ to induce an injection on homology is equivalent to the boundary maps $\partial$ in the long exact sequence

$$\cdots \xrightarrow{\partial} H_n(A) \to H_n(X) \to H_n(X, A) \to \cdots$$

in relative homology vanishing, and this is a tricky condition to verify. A sufficient condition is that $A$ is a retract of $X$. (And if you really want an injection on cohomology, as opposed to a surjection, then things are even weirder.)

Comment: Thank you for the helpful explanation.  You are correct, I am really more interested in an injection on cohomology.  I am currently doing a search for general knowledge of cohomologically injective symplectic embeddings of spheres in higher dimension symplectic manifolds.