# Homology of a space with an embedded torus

Tags: homology-cohomology, cw-complexes

I was wondering given a CW-complex $X$, can we by homological tools discern whether $X$ cannot have  torus as a subcomplex?

If I am not mistaken, for a $d$-dimensional torus, we have

$$ H_k(\mathbb{T}^d;\mathbb{Z})= \begin{cases} \mathbb{Z}^{\binom{d}{k}} &;0\leq k\leq d\\ 0 & ;k\geq d \end{cases} $$

My Question is if we assume that  $X$ contains a realization of $\mathbb{T}^d$ as a subcomplex, does that mean that $\mathbb{Z}^{\binom{d}{k}}$ is a sub-module of $H_k(X;\mathbb{Z})$?  It seems to me like a set of independent cycles in the subcomplex, should still be independent cycles in the whole complex. Is this indeed the case?

I saw in another [thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1648292/regarding-embeddings-and-homological-cohomological-injectivity), that 'embedding the spaces' does not imply 'embedding' the homology. But I don't see what breaks down in the intuition written above?

I am not strong in my comprehension of Homology, but I thought this might be a well resolved question which I could not find an answer to, by an online search.

Comment: Embed a torus in a ball, which is contractible and so has trivial homology.

Comment: @DavidSheard So that means that adding cells can be remove cycles, right?

Comment: Yes exactly. Take a 1D torus - a circle - which has first homology $\mathbb{Z}$. Attach a 2-cell to this circle to form a disk. The result is contractible.